# Detox mocking files

Tags: react-native, detox

I'm using Detox 9.0.4 and React-native 0.57.2, and am trying to mock files.
Following their [documentation](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Guide.Mocking.md) I added the `RN_SRC_EXT=e2e.js` env variable when running the build and added `getSourceExts: () => process.env.RN_SRC_EXT ? process.env.RN_SRC_EXT.split(',') : []` to our packager configuration (`rn-cli.config.js`).

This worked fine until we upgraded React-Native to 0.57 which uses the updated Metro Bundler, so I changed the `rn-cli.config.js` accordingly:

```
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');

module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    blacklistRE: blacklist([/react-native\/local-cli\/core\/__fixtures__.*/]),
    sourceExts: process.env.RN_SRC_EXT ? process.env.RN_SRC_EXT.split(',') : []
  }
};
```

But the `sourceExts` causes the regular build to fail.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the new syntax doesn't take JS files if you don't specify it explicitly, so the solution was to add it in each case.

The `rn-cli.config.js` file:

```
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');

module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    blacklistRE: blacklist([/react-native\/local-cli\/core\/__fixtures__.*/]),
    sourceExts: process.env.RN_SRC_EXT ? process.env.RN_SRC_EXT.split(',') : []
  }
};
```

And when you pass the `RN_SRC_EXT` variable, which in my case is in the npm command,  I also passed 'js' as the second extension:

```
"test:e2e-build": "RN_SRC_EXT='e2e.js,js' detox build -c ios.sim.release"
```

Comment: This mocking config its not working in react-native 0.61.5, any ideas?